# Paypal IPN - on storing variables

Tags: php, mysql, curl, paypal

In the paypal IPN system, paypal will make a request on your server with many parameters in the URL using curl. I'm wondering if I'm supposed to store each key/value in a separate field in the database, or if I should store the whole request as a string in a single field.

Which is the preferred or common method?

The main thing which is concerning me is, if later paypal decide to add more variables or deprecate old ones then the database would need to be altered. Storing values in separate fields also makes it a lot more difficult to store the order data when you have item_name# (an unknown number of variables) to store.

Is there any reason I should create a separate field in my database for each variable paypal will return?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, the only thing your ipn listener needs is "success" or "failure", and a id to identify the transaction.

Comment: @Dagon I need to store all of the response from paypal in my custom cart (amount paid, payer email, address, etc)

Comment: @Dagon how do you make your invoices?

Comment: i record the information on my site (address et al), then send them to paypal for payment, all i need back form paypal is the conformation that the payment was successful. Most (the ones i have worked with) open source shopping carts work this way. Most other payment gateways work this way - all they deal with is the payment; you store the transaction specifics and any user details you need on your site.

Comment: @Dagon I work on a site that uses magento & it gives more payment information which is useful to us later on (e.g. paypal verified/unverified, address confirmed/unconfirmed), so I thought it would be better to store all of the returned variables from paypal, but now i'm unsure

Comment: well it's your call. All I care about is the money is now in my account :-)

Comment: @Dagon Hmm I guess I just need to store a few variables then not all... btw the money isn't guaranteed in case of chargebacks so if the paypal payer is unverified we usually call them to confirm the order. thanks for your advice

Comment: By doing it the way @Dagon suggests, you will avoid the issue I ran into - customer's email/shipping address is different than their paypal email/billing address. Even names could be different (had some that paid using college roommates card)

Comment: yes i see that a lot, its odd paypal works like this, the major cc payment gateways will just tell you if the transaction worked. They don't want to deal with this other stuff, that should always be done on your site anyway.

Comment: @Sean however, if the billing address is different there is a higher risk of chargebacks, so the billing address is something i'd be storing. At the company I work for, we sometimes call the customer and ask them to repeat the billing address over the phone to verify they know they paid for the order

Comment: fake address in pay pal fake address on your site, i don't see any added benefit.

Comment: i don't know many "companies" using paypal when there are far better cheaper, and less problematic payment gateways, i have always considered pay pal only for the very small and cheap user (but that could just be me).

Comment: @dagon actually we use sagepay but paypal is one of the options available, and yes it is a small business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the least amount of information as possible. Don't store what you dont need. Also, I would recommend creating fields for each thing you want to store because this way later down the road if paypal does change their api all you have to change is your mapper between the database and paypal and not the string value you are parsing for each time.